# vb.net Window Form "hangman"

Tags: vb.net

i was making a type of hangman but i got stuck when the char get written in the label

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim SecretWord As String = "hello"
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Label2.Text = ""
        For i = 0 To SecretWord.Length - 1
            Label2.Text = Label2.Text & "_ "
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text <> "" And TextBox1.TextLength = 1 Then
            For i = 0 To SecretWord.Length - 1
                If SecretWord.Chars(i) = TextBox1.Text Then
                    ""What do i do when it finds the char?""
                End If
            Next
        Else
            MsgBox("Enter a letter!")
            TextBox1.Text = ""
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: Design]

Comment: So what exactly is the issue? Expected behavior?

Comment: What does " got stuck " mean? We need more information.

Comment: If char is found, get its index and replace the same indexed  "_" in Label.text to the char that was found

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each letter in your secret word, you are displaying "_ ", an underscore and a space.

That's a 1:2 ratio from your secretWord's characters to the label's text.

```
Secret Word:     h| |e| |l| |l| |o
Word Indexes:    0| |1| |2| |3| |4
Label Text:      _| |_| |_| |_| |_
Label Indexes:   0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8
```

If you look from the top down, you can see that the index of any character in your SecretWord string correlates with that 1:2 ratio. For example, "e" being at index 1 in the secret word is multiplied by 2 and is shown as the underscore at index 2 in Label2.Text.

The loop you have written is already going to have the index of the guessed letter, so all you really need to do at that point it substitute a character in Label2.Text at index (i * 2).

If you were were using other methods to store the secret word and build the label text it might be possible to do the substitution in a more concise manner, but as currently written you will need to first split the label text into an array, then change the appropriate character, and finally join it back together into a string:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To SecretWord.Length - 1
    If secretWord(i) = CChar(TextBox1.Text) Then
        'Get your array so you can change a character
        Dim labelChars As Char() = Label2.Text.ToCharArray()
        'Replace the underscore at the appropriate position with the real letter
        labelChars(i * 2) = secretWord(i)
        'Join the modified characters back into a string and update the label's text
        Label2.Text = New String(labelChars)
    End If
Next
```